# In jQuery how can I set "top,left" properties of an element with position values relative to the parent and not the document?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, positioning, css-position

`.offset([coordinates])` method set the coordinates of an element but only relative to the document. Then how can I set coordinates of an element but relative to the parent?

I found that `.position()` method get only "top,left" values relative to the parent, but it doesn't set any values.

I tried with

```
$("#mydiv").css({top: 200, left: 200});
```

but does not work.

Answer (score 253, accepted):

To set the position relative to the parent you need to set the `position:relative` of parent and `position:absolute` of the element

```
$("#mydiv").parent().css({position: 'relative'});
$("#mydiv").css({top: 200, left: 200, position:'absolute'});
```

This works because `position: absolute;` positions relatively to the closest **positioned** parent (i.e., the closest parent with any position property other than the default `static`).

Comment: `$("#mydiv").css({top: '200px', left: '200px', position:'absolute'});` <-- good
`$("#mydiv").css({top: '200', left: '200', position:'absolute'});` <-- bad.  Apparently, if position **values are strings**, you must include the units, or it'll have no effect.

Comment: That note about having a relative positioned parent saved me a lot of frustration. Thank you.

Answer (score 46):

```
$("#mydiv").css('top', 200);

$("#mydiv").css('left', 200);
```

Answer (score 13):

You could try jQuery UI's [.position](http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/) method.

```
$("#mydiv").position({
  of: $('#mydiv').parent(),
  my: 'left+200 top+200',
  at: 'left top'
});
```

***[Check the working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/sTC2F/)***

Comment: Beware that the method IS NOT position() from jQuery but position() from jQuery UI, that is a SETTER.

https://api.jqueryui.com/position/

Comment: @AdrianoG.V.Esposito, how to define right and bottom offset

Answer (score 7):

I found that if the value passed is a string type, it must be followed by 'px' (i.e. 90px), where if the value is an integer, it will append the px automatically.  the width and height properties are more forgiving (either type works).

```
var x = "90";
var y = "120"
$(selector).css( { left: x, top: y } )        //doesn't work
$(selector).css( { left: x + "px", top: y + "px" } )        //does work

x = 90;
y = 120;
$(selector).css( { left: x, top: y } )        //does work
```

Answer (score 7):

Code offset dynamic for dynamic page

```
var pos=$('#send').offset().top;
$('#loading').offset({ top : pos-220});
```

Answer (score 1):

Refreshing my memory on setting position, I'm coming to this so late I don't know if anyone else will see it, but --

I don't like setting position using `css()`, though often it's fine. I think the best bet is to use jQuery UI's `position()` setter as noted by xdazz. However if jQuery UI is, for some reason, not an option (yet jQuery is), I prefer this:

```
const leftOffset = 200;
const topOffset = 200;
let $div = $("#mydiv");
let baseOffset = $div.offsetParent().offset();
$div.offset({
  left: baseOffset.left + leftOffset,
  top: baseOffset.top + topOffset
});
```

This has the advantage of not arbitrarily setting `$div`'s parent to relative positioning (what if `$div`'s parent was, itself, absolute positioned inside something else?). I think the only major edge case is if `$div` doesn't have any `offsetParent`, not sure if it would return `document`, `null`, or something else entirely.

`offsetParent` has been available since jQuery 1.2.6, sometime in 2008, so this technique works now and when the original question was asked.

Answer (score 1):

Use `offset()` function of `jQuery`. Here it would be:

```
$container.offset({
        'left': 100,
        'top': mouse.y - ( event_state.mouse_y - event_state.container_top ) 
    });
```