# jQuery : Override existing css

Tags: jquery

In my project I have a js file in which top and left of a div has set and it changes dynamically.i tried to override it with the following code

```
  $("#buyoverlay").css('left',newaddwid);
  $("#buyoverlay").css('top',newaddhit);
```

here `newaddwid` and `newaddhit` are two variables

It works fine in `document.ready` function, but the next instance when position changes, js file top and left override this. How could i fix this problem?

Comment: show us how the values change and also the code that is supposedly overriding this

Comment: post some screen-shots or code sample. It might help other to help you.  Also have a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744928/in-jquery-how-can-i-set-top-left-properties-of-an-element-with-position-values

Answer (score 1):

Use your code under a function like:

```
function changepos(){
 $("#buyoverlay").css('left',newaddwid);
 $("#buyoverlay").css('top',newaddhit);
}
```

Now call the function on documeny.ready and the next instance too like.

```
changepos();
```